# Promise Chain Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm having a hard time with Promise chaining. I have a function that resolves through a bunch of promise, and I want another function that basically extends that promise chain, but I'm having a hard time. So this is how it looks like.

```
function foo() {
  new Promise(function (res, re) {
    /* code */
  }).then(function() {
    /* code */
  }).then(function() {
    /* code */
  }).then(function() {
    /* code */
  });
}
```

I want function extend() {} to extend the promise chain in foo. I tried wrapping foo as a promise, but for some reason that doesn't quite work either. Is there a way of doing this without code duplication? Thank you.

Comment: just `return` your promise from `foo`. Then you can extend it.

Answer (score 4):

Just return the promise chain from `foo`:

```
return new Promise(/*...*/).then(/*...*/)
```

Then its as easy as:

```
foo().then(/*...*/)
```

Comment: Gotchu. Thanks.
I was wondering why this approach does work:

    `function foo2() { new Promise(function(res,rej) {
      res(foo())
      })
    }`